# How to add a DOWN limit switch to a Harbor Freight (Pittsburgh) hoist

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, ac, switches

I am using a pittsburgh hoist to raise and lower a large curtain. The hoist has a built in limit switch to stop when it raises to a certain point. I need to add another limit switch to stop the hoist from moving down. The trick is to get the new limit switch to behave like the other one in that it only stops the motor from turning one direction while allowing motion in the opposite direction to move away from the limit.

How and where do I need to modify this hoist to add a down limit switch that stops the hoist from letting out cable when it is triggered, but still allows the hoist to take the cable back up? Anything is helpful.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added S4, the 2nd limit switch. Probably you need an additional wire between S1 and the wiring box.

[image: LimitSwitch2]

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frhBCS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn schematic.*

There's something wrong with your wire tracing, I think. Both capacitors are in parallel and aren't in circuit when moving up. Can you retrace it?

Comment: I found this schematic for the old version of the hoist I am using. It is from the manual. can you work with this?

Comment: NOPE NOPE NOPE  "Pittsburgh" / "Harbor Freight".  Do not expect ANY schematic to be correct - They are famous for being wrong.   Especially one for another model.  You gotta trace this out and make darn sure you got it all correct.  IMO you'll be much better off in the long run to just buy a quality hoist that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The limit switch goes between the top right terminal of S1 and the wires that currently connect to there.

This means you'll need to upgrade the handset to a 5 conductor cable.

Or maybe not, I don't understand the left half of the switch. All it does is disconnect the capacitors in the stop position, I don't see how that's useful, but they spent money on it....